# PHP upload script error

Tags: php, file-upload

Im new to php as to this site... Im trying to make site where you will upload cfg from CSGO. My PHP script for it does not work :(. I want to: write down ip of uploader,check if file name is cfg.rar,check if file uploads/typed username already exist - if yes than read and compare password from password.txt with the typed one - wrong = error/good = delete existing cfg,if file not exist:create dir: uploads/typed username,create file in: password.txt with the typed password,check file size,check file type (.rar),check if upload was aborted

php code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("ip.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "\n". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt . basename( $_POST['name']));
fclose($myfile);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_folder = $target_dir . $_POST['name'] . "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_POST['name'] . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
if(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) == "cfg.rar") {
        echo "FILE IS AN cfg.rar";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "FILE IS NOT AN cfg.rar.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if file already exists
if (!file_exists($target_folder)) {
    $password = file_get_contents($target_folder . "password.txt");
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $password) {
    echo "THIS NAME ALREADY EXIST!";
    echo "IF IT'S YOURS, TRY TO RE-ENTER THE PASSWORD!";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        unlink($target_file);
    }
}
else
{
    mkdir($target_folder);
    $fopenh = fopen($target_folder . "/pass.txt", "c");
    fwrite($fopenh, $_POST['password']);
    fclose($fopenh);
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 150000) {
    echo "SORRY, YOUR FILE IS TOO LARGE.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "rar" ) {
    echo "SORRY, ONLY cfg.rar FILES ARE ALLOWED.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "SORRY, YOUR FILE WAS NOT UPLOADED.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "THE FILE ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " HAS BEEN UPLOADED.";
    } else {
        echo "SORRY, THE FILE COULD NOT BE UPLOADED!.";
    }
}
?>`
```

html code:

```html
<center><form action="upload.php" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br/>
            Select cfg.rar to upload:<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" name="submit">
            </form>
            </br>
            <p>By uploading a file you accept, that this site will save your ip address!</p></center>
```

Thank you for help :)
Going to sleep :3

Comment: By visiting `/uploads/someones_name/password.txt` I can steam someones password. Nice.

Comment: Im new in php :D i was already thinking about it but how to prevent it? :(

Comment: you should put those files with password into publicly unaccesible location, or deny access to them in a .htaccess file. You should also never save passwords in plain text, you should [hash them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and then [verify it by comparing hashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with (uploading) files, a valid enctype is required in forms.

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tags.

Read the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

and make sure the folder you are uploading to, has the proper permissions to write to it.

Use error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php